# Load specific scope configuration data in Multi site

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.4.2, redis, system-configuration

I have three websites in the single Magento 2.4.2 application. When I load any one of the website it will load all the websites configurations data in the configuration cache. I'm looking for a way to load specific scope data instead of loading all.

**Reproduce steps:**

1. Create three websites and each has one store and one store view.
   [image]
2. Configure Redis for [page cache, default cache and session](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html).
3. Flush Magento cache.
4. Load **website_two** URL frontend and check the redis.

**Expecting result:**

Redis stored only website_two scope data.

**Actual result:**

Redis stored all the websites and store configurations.
[image]

For Redis GUI, I'm using this [tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-commander).

```
$ redis-commander --redis-host=172.18.0.6
Using scan instead of keys
No Save: false
listening on 0.0.0.0:8081
access with browser at http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

When the sites count increases, that time PHP took more memory to create the configuration cache on the first time load. Approximately 600 sites utilize 2-3GB of PHP memory to create a configuration cache for each website's first-time load.

**Example**

```
website.one -> utilize 2-3GB PHP memory
website.one/* -> Utilize 200MB, because configuration cache generated above.
website.two -> utilize 2-3GB PHP memory
website.two/* -> Utilize 200MB, because configuration cache generated above.
```

If 20+ uncached website URLs are loading concurrently, it will down the server.

I have seen the below comments in core code `vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php` but not sure about what is the cleaner approach.

```
/**
 * Get configuration value by path
 *
 * System configuration is separated by scopes (default, websites, stores). Configuration of a scope is inherited
 * from its parent scope (store inherits website).
 *
 * Because there can be many scopes on single instance of application, the configuration data can be pretty large,
 * so it does not make sense to load all of it on every application request. That is why we cache configuration
 * data by scope and only load configuration scope when a value from that scope is requested.
 *
 * Possible path values:
 * '' - will return whole system configuration (default scope + all other scopes)
 * 'default' - will return all default scope configuration values
 * '{scopeType}' - will return data from all scopes of a specified {scopeType} (websites, stores)
 * '{scopeType}/{scopeCode}' - will return data for all values of the scope specified by {scopeCode} and scope type
 * '{scopeType}/{scopeCode}/some/config/variable' - will return value of the config variable in the specified scope
 *
 * @inheritdoc
 * @since 100.1.2
 */
public function get($path = '')
{
    if ($path === '') {
        $this->data = array_replace_recursive($this->loadAllData(), $this->data);

        return $this->data;
    }

    return $this->getWithParts($path);
}
```

Thanks in advance.